# I can't run WPS Office 11 in Ubuntu Disco

Tags: wps-office

I downloaded the .deb file from the official website and installed with Software Installer. However, the program doesn't run.

How do I get WPS Office 11 to work?

Comment: I don't use it, but if you were to download the .deb, and `sudo dpkg -i file.deb` and provide the output (ie. copy/paste into your question) from the attempt to install the file, many people here might be able to help you.

Comment: Their forum seems to be full of spam posts. I wonder where potential users can get support.

Comment: [This link](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/wps-office-11-2019-for-linux-released.html) mentions that the writer couldn't get WPS Office 11 to work on Ubuntu 18.10 whereas it worked on Ubuntu 18.04. The flatpak version was reported to work on Ubuntu 18.10. The link didn't mention 19.04.

Comment: WPS is now also available as snap.

Comment: In ubuntu 19.04 i use sudo dpkg -i <file>.deb, this is work. Snap version not up to date, that version is 10... *Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

After going from solution to solution, wasting both hours and bandwidth. Here is the final solution that works in 2020 for me in Ubuntu 18-04 Bionic

**Setup and install FlatHub**

Flathub is a build and distribution service for Flatpak applications. Its goal is to act as a central hub for making desktop applications available to users. 
Use this link for instructions https://flatpak.org/setup/

When setup is complete, install **WPS-Office** (Latest 11.1.0.9080) from the [FlatHub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.wps.Office) store.

```
flatpak install flathub com.wps.Office
flatpak run com.wps.Office
```

Hope this works out for you, not sure what to do if it doesn't

**Below are methods that don't work**

- Downloading from Snap Store - Verison is old (v 10.1.0.6757)
- The .deb package from WPS website doesn't work as it is missing some critical packages and crashes constantly.
- The package available at the Software Center in Ubuntu is old (v 10.1.0.6757) with the same snap package as its source.

Comment: Maybe this is good idea, but i don't like flatpak so much. Is more data to be downloaded.

Comment: Indeed they take up more space but the ability to pack all dependencies together with Flatpak's containerized runtime is the reason some of the applications run as smoothly as they do. Three years later, I have a dozen applications installed using Flatpak. Life. is good and they don't auto-update.