# Install LibreOffice-Writer Only not LibreOffice whole package

Tags: apt, libreoffice

I have Installed Ubuntu 18.04.2 minimal Installation.

I will use only LibreOffice-Writer, Is there a way to Install Only this?

Comment: @ggdx Actually, [it's closed-source and Linux support is shaky.](https://securityonline.info/wps-office-linux-project-aborts-planned-open-source-linux-code/)

Comment: @ggdx maybe you'd like to help out answering https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139691/i-cant-run-wps-office-11-in-ubuntu-disco.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes! `sudo apt install libreoffice-writer` will install that package as well as certain other core LibreOffice packages. You will need to install the help package separately if you want help offline.

See the following output:

```
$ apt list --installed | grep -i libreoffice

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libreoffice-base-core/bionic,now 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libreoffice-calc/bionic,now 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1 amd64 [installed]
libreoffice-common/bionic,bionic,now 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1 all [installed,automatic]
libreoffice-core/bionic,now 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libreoffice-gtk3/bionic,now 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1 amd64 [installed]
libreoffice-help-en-us/bionic,bionic,now 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1 all [installed]
libreoffice-math/bionic,now 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libreoffice-style-breeze/bionic,bionic,now 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1 all [installed,automatic]
libreoffice-style-colibre/bionic,bionic,now 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1 all [installed,automatic]
libreoffice-style-tango/bionic,bionic,now 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1 all [installed,automatic]
libreoffice-writer/bionic,now 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1 amd64 [installed]
$
```

The ones listed as "installed" are what I installed. The rest listed as "installed,automatic" come in as a matter of course.

---

You can do a "dry run" to see what *would* be installed using `-s` to specify you're only running a simulation and so `sudo` isn't needed.

With 19.04,

```
apt install -s libreoffice
```

gives me

> 0 upgraded, **83 newly installed**, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Whereas

```
apt install -s libreoffice-writer
```

gives me

> 0 upgraded, **28 newly installed**, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: I'll check in a 19.04 VM and in an 18.04 VM and post back.

Answer (score 6):

This command will install only LibreOffice Writer without any recommended packages:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends libreoffice-writer libreoffice-gtk3
```

Comment: seems.. this is the one i was looking for.. i need to try it.. but it takes time to try.. if you can show the difference clearly like DK Bose showed the difference in terms of packages..

Comment: I have purged completely libreoffice* from my system and then tried with --no-install-recommends and did not find major difference in terms of saving the space by no recommended packages.. it is showing 26 in place of 28.. also the sizes comparison is 74 & 76MB

Comment: @PRATAP, I hope you've installed the *libreoffice-gtk3* package. That will ensure that your LibreOffice looks decent.

Comment: no i did only what you mentioned in your answer.. thats it.. i dont know such a gtk3 another package is available

Comment: Use 'apt-cache show <package>' to look at the dependencies of packages you want to install.  Some may be unavoidable.  For example libreoffice-core installs a ton of dependencies.  If you really want to go minimal then download LibreOffice binary directly from LibreOffice and do a minimal install.

Comment: this is interesting.. but i don't know binary and the steps to installation..

Comment: Go to the download link at libreoffice.org

Comment: To install calc only, just replace `writer` with `calc`.